# Get another value form object if one is empty angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops

I have some object like this

```
outgoingInvoices = [{
        invoiceRecipientName: "Test"
        invoiceResourceId: "20.pdf"
    },
    {
        invoiceRecipientName: "Test"
        invoiceResourceId: ""
    },
    {
        invoiceRecipientName: "Test"
        invoiceResourceId: "20.pdf"
    }.
];
```

I need to get first from object like this, not a problem

```
this.invoiceResourceId[0].invoiceResourceId;
```

But i have problem what if there is no value in first one, then i have to take the second one if there no value in second one take third and so on. And to be null if there is no value in anyone :(

I have tried for loop but i think there is better way in ES6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map your array to one that only has the `invoiceResourceId`, then filter it to remove `null`s, and if the resulting array is empty simply return `null`.

```
const resourceIds = outgoingInvoices.map(x => x.invoiceResourceId).filter(y => y);
const result = resourceIds.length ? resourceIds[0] : null;
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake, if there is no value in first one, i have edit the question, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not think that there is anything wrong with loops (when they are the appropiate solution), but if you were to do it "the functional programming way" you could use Array.prototype.reduce:

```
outgoingInvoices.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev || curr.invoiceResourceId;
}, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Array.find`. It will return first matching object or null.

```js
var outgoingInvoices = [{
    invoiceRecipientName: "Test",
    invoiceResourceId: ""
  },
  {
    invoiceRecipientName: "Test",
    invoiceResourceId: "abc"
  },
  {
    invoiceRecipientName: "Test",
    invoiceResourceId: "20.pdf"
  }
];

var invoice = outgoingInvoices.find((inv) => !!inv.invoiceResourceId);
var output = !!invoice ? invoice.invoiceResourceId : invoice;

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply reduce the array to a first non-false value

`const firstNonFalse = outgoingInvoices.reduce(
     (acc,invoice)=> acc || invoice.invoiceResourceId,
      null)`

null, as the last argument in the reduce method, sets the default value for acc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
outgoingInvoices.find( invoice => invoice.invoiceResourceId != '' );
```